# Eclipse IDE Tern ES6 Validation & Auto-Complete

Tags: eclipse, validation, autocomplete, eslint, tern

I'm having issues setting up validation via Tern with ESLint. I disabled the internal parsing as shown, http://tools.jboss.org/documentation/whatsnew/jbosstools/4.3.0.Final.html#javascript-development-tools-improvements, and I enabled ESLint. In the project properties `javascript > Tern > Validation > ESLint` I specified the `.eslintrc` config file to use (also tried `eslint.json`).

I can run ESLint from the command line and it gives me all the nice errors to fix, but I don't know why it's not work in Eclipse via Tern. Also I enabled the jQ library, but it's not giving me auto-complete either. I'm not sure if there's some other configuration I'm missing for Tern or not.

Comment: You have posted your question too at https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/issues/383

Comment: Yeah, I posted there after I found the GH and not getting a reply here.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it expects only the rules in the configuration.

Instead of:

```
{
    "env": { ... },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "parserOptions": { ... },
    "rules": {
        "no-trailing-spaces" : "error"
    }
}
```

It's just looking for:

```
{
    "no-trailing-spaces" : "error"
}
```